# Unknown wallet address on private development chain

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

Apologies in advance for the long post. I'm new to Ethereum and don't know which details are significant and which are not.

I'm trying to learn about dapps by following an example in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1260115879). My system is Windows 10-based. The book tells me first to sync an Ethereum node, which I do using

```
geth --datadir d:\Ethereum\geth
```

This is **not** my `%APPDATA` directory (that drive is too small to host the node).

So that was successful. Next step is to create and configure a private development chain, which I do using this:

```
geth --dev --datadir D:\SampleDapp\privatenet --ipcpath D:\Ethereum\geth.ipc --networkid 45 --rpc --rpcapi web3,net,eth,personal --rpccorsdomain "*" --mine console
```

The book tells me that for Mist to interact with the IPC file it must be located with the main node, therefore I set it up that way.

So far, so good. Next I create a simple contract in Solidity, which successfully compiles. Now we come to the deployment, which the book says is done with this Node.js script:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var fs = require('fs');
var exec = require('child_process').execSync;

var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
var walletAddress = web3.eth.accounts[0];
console.log(walletAddress);
web3.personal.unlockAccount(walletAddress, process.argv[2]);

var abi = fs.readFileSync('bin/peerbet.sol:Bet.abi');
var PeerBet = web3.eth.Contract(abi);

var compiled = '0x' + fs.readFileSync('bin/Bet.bin');
var peerbet = PeerBet.new({
    from: walletAddress,
    data: compiled,
    gas: 40e5,
    gasPrice: 20e9
}, function (e, contract) {
    if (e) console.log(e);

    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address +
            ' transaction hash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
        fs.writeFileSync('contract_address', contract.address);
    }
});
```

This is where the problem is. The wallet address found at `web3.eth.accounts[0]` is one I've never seen before. I have two wallets on my system (one set up by Mist, and one by MetaMask), but neither of those addresses correspond to the address I'm getting in this script. Since I don't know where the wallet address came from, I don't know its private key, password, passphrase, or whatever. So, two questions: where did this wallet address come from, and what do I need to provide as an argument to get `web3.personal.unlockAccount()` to work? Thanks.

Comment: What is the content of your D:\SampleDapp\privatenet\keystore directory? Can you find there the address of ``web3.eth.accounts[0]``?

Comment: @ivicaa Thanks! OK, in that directory is a JSON file with the address, so now I know where we're getting the address. Now how would I find the password (passphrase? private key?) needed for the call to `web3.personal.unlockAccount()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two accounts must come from your dev node -> `D:\SampleDapp\privatenet\keystore`

Most probably you created them at some point and now you can not remember anymore.

Anyway, you can simply recreate the datadir. Simply delete `D:\SampleDapp\privatenet` and call the `geth --dev ...` command again. On the console create as many accounts as you need with `personal.newAccount()`. Then rerun your nodejs test-script.

Comment: It actually appears that when I first started the dev node it created the account automatically (I didn't create it, just the two accounts that are on the main node). I used `personal.newAccount()` on the console and created a new account, which now shows up as web3.eth.accounts[1]. Thanks for the help!

Comment: PS--I just figured out that the account that gets created when the chain is initialized has a balance of ETH and no passphrase. I deleted the `privatenet` directory, then ran the command again. In the console I typed `eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])` and got that the account has 1.16e+77 ETH. Calling `personal.unlockAccount(address, "")` succeeds and allows use of the account.